# Portable Executable file format

Tags: portable-executable

I'm doing some research on the PE format, but I'm having trouble understanding some things ... for example, in various documentations found the signature "PE\0\0' must be in position 0x80 of file, so, I generated a 2 exes using the Digital Mars C/C++ compiler and MVC++ compiler...

In DMC compiler, the PE signature is in 0x60 position, and in MSC++ the PE signature is in 0xE8 postions...

What would be the correct way to calculate this?

In the executable generated by MSC++ I found this ( look the picture ), what is this???

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wjVl7kx.png]

Comment: First hit for me when googling `PE File Format`: [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) which indicates you need to find the offset from the DOS header's `e_lfsnew` member. It's not at a fixed offset like `0x80`.

Comment: Obvious!, I had forgotten that!!... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure, the last variable is the e_lfanew variable, this indicates where the PE file header is located